# Override timezone region settings in selenium chromedriver

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

When running selenium on a system with UK timezone the input[type="date"] element expects the date in a different format than when running on a system with a timezone preference of US.

e.g.
UK DD-MM-YYYY
US MM-DD-YYYY

Is there a way to override this settings to ensure it'll run on all systems regardless of what the OS timezone preference is.

selenium v3